# How to get format settings of field in drupal 8?

Tags: field, drupal-8

I have a drupal 8 project and I was requested by my customer to get format settings of field in content type to respond to an api for mobile app. I created a new module, and trying to get data of format settings. But haven't succeed. I just get all setting of a field, but not display settings of field in content type.

On picture below, I want get all data of format column, and show it as a json. Please help me. Thanks so much!
[image]

Comment: This item on Drupal Answers might be of help to you: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/240002/how-to-apply-a-field-formatter-to-a-node-field-programmatically/240008

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extract the formatter settings for a specific field, you can use this option:

```php
/** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityDisplayRepository $entityDisplayRepository */
$entityDisplayRepository = \Drupal::service('entity_display.repository');
$productViewDisplay = $entityDisplayRepository->getViewDisplay('node', 'page', 'teaser' /* optional */);
$all_formatters_settings = $productViewDisplay->get('content');

$formatter_settings = $all_formatters_settings['field_my_field'];
```

If you need to get the settings for the widget, you can similarly call the function `getFormDisplay()` in the repository instead of `getViewDisplay()`:

```php
/** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityDisplayRepository $entityDisplayRepository */
$entityDisplayRepository = \Drupal::service('entity_display.repository');
$productViewDisplay = $entityDisplayRepository->getFormDisplay('node', 'page', 'teaser' /* optional */);
$all_formatters_settings = $productViewDisplay->get('content');

$formatter_settings = $all_formatters_settings['field_my_field'];
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to get the formatter settings.

```
$formatter_settings = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('entity_view_display')
  ->load("entity_type_id.entity_bundle.view_mode")
  ->getRenderer('field_logo_kataloga')
  ->getSettings();
```